# C++ Resetting Rain Counter Daily

Tags: c++, arduino

So I'm working on a project that sniffs and decodes RF data off of my accurate 5 in 1 weather station which I'm then assigning to variables to use in my code. The problem I'm having is the data coming off the weather station for the rain tip bucket is an endless running value. If I reset the weather station by pulling the batteries out the rain tip bucket counter will go to 0. I would like to take the endless running value and reset it back to zero in my code each day without resetting the weather station.

Could someone point me in the right direction on achieving this result?

Comment: Just use a global offset, to thich you add the daily value on the end of the day. Then you can do `dailyValue = runningData - offset` and you will start with zero. Note that the value will overflow at some point...

Comment: @frankenapps thanks for the suggestion. That did work as I was needed it too. What do you think the best course of action for resetting that offset value so that I could try preventing overflow? Do you happen to know how long before a overflow would ocurr? If I could purge the offset variable data every month, that would meet my needs.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is, couldn't I just create a schedule monthly that will just `offset = 0;` to clear out any stored memory and start from scratch so that I don't cause an overflow? Again, thank you for all of your help as I was losing my mind over this and you saved me.

Comment: I don't think that can work. But really I personally wouldn't worry to much about the value overflowing, if the perciption is measured in mm or l/m^2 and you store your offset in a `float` which can hold up to 3.4028235E+38, an overflow would only occur after 1.701e+35 years assuming a yearly perciption of 2000mm / l/m^2...

Comment: Perfect, well thanks again for your help.